# Interpreting last date of tax submission US

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I was wondering if last date of submission of US taxes for 2017 means that tax should reach IRS by April 18 or should be posted to IRS by April 18. Any references would be helpful.

Comment: Today is April 18. This question just occurred to you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [USPS](https://www.usps.com/taxes/welcome.htm):

> Federal Tax Deadlines. If your tax return is **postmarked** by April 18,
>   2017 or October 16, 2017 (extension), the IRS considers it filed on
>   time.

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [IRS](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc301.html):

> Your return is considered filed on time if the envelope is properly
> addressed, postmarked, and deposited in the mail by the due date.

So on top of postmarking it, it has to be properly addressed as well. So if it gets returned to you because the address was wrong, then you might be penalized.

Comment: This is a specific (but common) case of the 'postmark rule' https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/7502